# What diagram or data visualization methods are usually used for statistics such as lines of code?

Tags: architecture, visualization, diagram

Context: You have a huge code project with dozens of software components. You have the following statistics: number of lines of code for each component, 3rd party dependencies, Inter component dependency and code coverage.
Problem: Do a clear data visualization for the statistics we have.

What diagrams or data visualization method you recommend for the number of lines of code? An online example is https://informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/million-lines-of-code/

But I was wondering if there are better solutions than column graphics

An online example is https://informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/million-lines-of-code